# NestJs authentication with OAuth2 token doesn't appears con Swagger's calls

Tags: oauth-2.0, nestjs, swagger-ui

In an application made with NestJs I've the follow Swagger configurations.

If I insert the token directly in the BearerAuth Swagger login the token will send with the correct header for all API calls, but if I use OAuth2 login swagger get the right token but don't attach it to the API calls.

```
  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('API')
    .setDescription('API description')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addServer('http://localhost:9000', 'Local Development')
    .addBearerAuth()
    .addOAuth2({
      type: 'oauth2',
      scheme: 'bearer',
      bearerFormat: 'JWT',
      in: 'header',
      flows: {
        password: {
          tokenUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/api/v1/auth/swagger-login',
          scopes: {},
        },
      },
      description: 'OAuth2 Authentication with Username and Password',
    })
    .build();
```